# Get lonLat-coordinates of a new point (vector layer)

Tags: events, coordinates, openlayers

I would like in openlayers set a new point in a Vectorlayer, if a "creation mode" is activated.
For that I adopt code from here:
http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.13.1/examples/click-handler.html
It works, but I get xy-coordinates of the new point only, but not the lonLat-coordinates.  map.getLonLatFromPixel(e.xy) doesent work. I have no idea why. Maybe someone can help me.

```
OpenLayers.Control.Click = OpenLayers.Class(OpenLayers.Control, {
  defaultHandlerOptions: {'single': true, 'double': false, 'pixelTolerance': 0, 'stopSingle': false, 'stopDouble': false},
  initialize: function(options) {this.handlerOptions = OpenLayers.Util.extend({}, this.defaultHandlerOptions);
  OpenLayers.Control.prototype.initialize.apply(this, arguments);
    this.handler = new OpenLayers.Handler.Click(this, {'click': this.onClick,'dblclick': this.onDblclick}, this.handlerOptions);},
  onClick: function(e) {
    var toProjection = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326");
    //var lonLat = map.getLonLatFromPixel(e.xy).transform(map.getProjectionObject(), toProjection);
    var output = document.getElementById(this.key + "Output");
    var msg = e.xy;//.transform(new OpenLayers.Projection(proj), new OpenLayers.Projection(displproj));//.transform(new OpenLayers.Projection(displproj),new OpenLayers.Projection(proj));
    output.value = output.value + msg + "\r\n";},
  onDblclick: function(evt) {
    var output = document.getElementById(this.key + "Output");
    var msg = "dblclick " + e.xy;
    output.value = output.value + msg + "\n";
  }
});
```

Before I tried an other way I prefere:

http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/editingtoolbar-outside.html

In this case i didnt get any coordinates.

Thank you in advance.

Best regards
Ambrose

Answer (score 0):

this here works for me:

```
map.events.register('click', map, function (e) {
var lonlat = map.getLonLatFromViewPortPx(e.xy);
});
```